# Asymptotic behaviour of sum of inverse matrix elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering if anyone knows if some theory exists on the following problem. I'm considering the minimization problem $h^2\boldsymbol{v}M_N\boldsymbol{v}$ subject to $\boldsymbol{1}_N^T\boldsymbol{v}=-\frac{X}{h}$, where $\boldsymbol{1}_N$ is the $N\times1$ vector filled with ones, $h=1/N$ and $M_N$ is an $N\times N$ matrix with elements $(M_N)_{ij}=G\left(\frac{|i-j|}{N-1}\right)$, where $G$ is some function. (Therefore $M_N$ is a symmetric Toeplitz matrix, if that is of importance.) The function $G$ is such that $M_N$ is always positive definite (so $G$ is positive definite in the sense of Bochner). It is easy to prove using Lagrange multipliers that the minimum attainable cost is $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol{1}_N^TM_N^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}_N}$.

I'm looking to prove that if $G$ is also convex, nonconstant and nonincreasing, then the minimum cost can not go to zero, i.e., $\boldsymbol{1}_N^TM_N^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}_N$ does not tend to infinity.

Can anyone provide some insight into this problem? I have tried to write  $\boldsymbol{1}_N^TM_N^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}_N$ as $\sum_{k=1}^N \lambda_k^{-1} Q_{k\cdot}Q_{\cdot k}$, where $M_N=Q\Lambda Q^T$, but this does not seem to help as the eigenvalues can go to zero (and they do), so you would have to be able to say something about the eigenvectors, where I got lost.