# Relationship between sum of element of a matrix and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Say we have a positive definite maxtrix, $M$, of size $m$. Then is there any relationship between $A=eMe'$ and $B=eM^{-1}e'$ for large $m$? I would like to claim something like $AB \sim m^2$ for large $m$. Is such a relationship possible?

Many thanks for your hints.

Comment: What are $e$ and $e'$? Any relation between them or to A,B? What does it mean by $AB \sim m^2?$

Comment: @Aman I guess that $e=(1,1  \cdots 1)$ so that $A$ is the sum of the elements of $M$

Comment: @leonbloy many thanks for clarifications :-)

Comment: @Aman I used $e$ but had to define it ... it might not be standard for all text books. thanks for mentioning this :-)

Comment: Related questions (few answers): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488296/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sum-of-inverse-matrix-elements  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063551/asymptotic-behaviour-of-the-sum-of-all-elements-of-an-inverse-symmetric-toeplitz  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45087/tight-bound-for-sum-of-entries-of-the-inverse-of-a-nonnegative-matrix http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432221/sum-of-all-entries-of-the-inverse-matrix-of-a-positive-definite-symmetric-matri

Comment: @leonbloy many thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but gives some of the ideas.

Since $M$ is positive definite, we can write $M=QDQ^T$ where $Q$ is orthonormal and $D$ is diagonal.  Then $M^{-1}=QD^{-1}Q^T$.  Since $D$ is diagonal, $D^{-1}$ is just the inverse of the diagonal elements.

Suppose that $e=(1,\cdots,1)$.  Then $eMe^T=(eQ)D(eQ)^T$.  On the other hand, $eM^{-1}e^T=(eQ)D^{-1}(eQ)^T$.  If we write $eQ=\sum a_ie_i$, then $eMe^T=\sum a_i^2d_i$ and $eM^{-1}e^T=\sum \frac{a_i^2}{d_i}$.  Observe that since $Q$ is orthonormal, $eQe^T=(e,e)=n$.  Therefore, $\sum a_i=n$.

Observe that $AB=\left(\sum a_i^2d_i\right)\left(\sum \frac{a_i^2}{d_i}\right)\geq \left(\sum (a_i\sqrt{d_i})\left(\frac{a_i}{\sqrt{d_i}}\right)\right)^2=\left(\sum a_i^2\right)^2$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  Since $\sum a_i=n$, the smallest that $\sum a_i^2$ coud be is when each $a_i=1$, so the sum would be $n$.  In other words, $AB\geq n^2$.  $AB$ could, however, be arbitrarily large if, perhaps one $d_i$ is especially small and another is reasonably large.

Comment: Many thanks. This is a nice approach. +1